# Heap Generation 2 and Large Object Heap climbs

Tags: memory-leaks, garbage-collection, jetbrains-ide

I am not sure if I am posting to the right StackOverFlow forum but here goes.

I have a C# desktop app.  It receives images from 4 analogue cameras and it tries to detect motion and if so it saves it.

When I leave the app running say over a 24hr cycle I notice the Private Working Set has climbed by almost 500% in Task manager.

Now, I know using Task Manager is not a good idea but it does give me an indication if something is wrong.

To that end I purchase dotMemory profiler from JetBrains.

I have used its tools to determine that the Heap Generation 2 increases a lot in size. Then to a lesser degree the Large Object Heap as well.

The latter is a surprise as the image size is 360x238 and the byte array size is always less than 20K.

So, my issues are:

Should I explicitly call GC.Collect(2) for instance?
Should I be worried that my app is somehow responsible for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Andrew, my recommendation is to take memory snapshot in dotMemory, than explore it to find what retains most of the memory. [This video](http://youtu.be/0jiUb2hb9xs?list=PLQ176FUIyIUbEfA-XkqEBBNaU28RvtWEL) will help you. If you not sure about GC.Collect, you can just tap "Force GC" button it will collect all available garbage in your app.[image]

Comment: Hi, yes I did the Force GC and it had no affect which is weird as it should have forced it down I would have thought? Will look at the video now. Thanks :)